# Heatmap widget in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, heatmap

I'm creating the heat map of a function with tuneable exponent. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm


alpha0 = 2.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

bining = np.logspace(1, 10, 1000)
x = y = bining
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = [[0 for i in xrange(len(x) - 1)] for j in xrange(len(y) - 1) ]

for i in xrange(len(x) - 1):
    for j in xrange(len(y) - 1):
        Z[i][j] = 1./((x[i]+y[j])**(2+alpha0))

Z = np.array(Z)

im = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral, norm=LogNorm())

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axexp  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
sexp = Slider(axexp, r"$\alpha$", 0.1, 10.0, valinit=alpha0)


def update(val):

    alpha = sexp.val
    Z = [[0 for i in xrange(len(x) - 1)] for j in xrange(len(y) - 1) ]
    for i in xrange(len(x) - 1):
        for j in xrange(len(y) - 1):
            Z[i][j] = 1./((x[i]+y[j])**(2+alpha))
    Z = np.array(Z)
    plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral, norm=LogNorm())
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sexp.on_changed(update)
```

It creates the figure and the slider, but when I try to change the exponent value, the heat map is not affected.
So my question, why is it not working and how can I solve it ? Also, widgets can be saved ? In what format ? Eventually I would use in a Beamer (LaTeX) presentation.
Thank you !

Comment: In your update you should update the object returned by `pcolormesh` not creating a new one.  Also, you should use sumpy for broadcasting, `Z = 1 / (x + y)**(2 + alpha)`

Comment: @tcaswell, thanks for your comment. I'm afraid I do not know how to 'update' my pcolormesh object (the syntax). Could you elaborate more on that, please ?